# SFTP Login Success - 404 Error In Browser

Tags: ftp, hosting, sftp, vps

This is my first time working with SFTP. I'm used to using a cPanel with a hosting company (like JustHost or GoDaddy, etc.).

I'm able to log in to my SFTP server through FileZilla and I'm able to upload files onto the server but when I go to visit the page on my web browser, it gives me a 404 error. For example, let's say my IP address for the server is:

```
123.45.67.89
```

I have the logins and I use them in FileZilla and put files in. And then I want to navigate to a file (in this case I'll use the phpMyAdmin directory I've created since that's what I'm trying). In the browser I write:

```
123.45.67.89/phpMyAdmin/setup/
```

This directory exists and has an index.php file in it but when I try to go to it, the browser gives me a 404 error. Am I missing a step here? Do I need to somehow work the login credentials into the URL? I've tried other paths too and they don't work either.

Thanks for your help!

---

EDIT

---

I just realized that with SFTP, the browser uses the information that's in the /var/www/html/ folder to display. I can navigate to those directories by just simply typing the directory name in. I suppose my question now is how do I get to the root directory in my web browser. Using just the 123.45.67.89/ defaults to the /var/www/html/ folder...

Answer (score 0):

Which web server do you use? If it's **Apache** you should learn about **apache virtual hosts** and modify the apache configuration file (usually on /etc/apache2).

See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for more details.